Python Kmeans consistently label clusters
I have a high dimension variable dataset which I want to classify into different groups. The data within can be confidently classified into 5 distinct groups.
I want to use the result of this clusterization process to create visual charts showcasing the difference within the resulting groups. As part of this task, I want to label each cluster so that instead of showing cluster 0 I show Industrial cluster.
However, since Kmeans is a random algorithm, it could happen that cluster 0 stops being the Industrial cluster. I've already set a random seed in my code to prevent this, but I expect my dataset to grow in the future.
I'm positive this could have the same effect as a random seed. I want to know how to consistently label my clusters and not worry when the numerical labels of the clusters get rearranged due to random changes in the data. So far the only idea I have is to use a data point from each expected cluster to change the cluster label automatically but I want a more robust solution.

It sounds like you are trying to use kmeans as a replacement for an attribute-based or hierarchical clustering method.  If the distinction between the clusters is so clear, why not figure out what makes each cluster unique and write some code that applies labels based on those characteristics?

The main reason I've used Kmeans is that it's the simplest algorithm I know. Some of the data does lie in between clusters and is not so easy to classify, though. I guess I can manually check for the desired characteristics and achieve the same result.

One workaround for this would be to keep track of cluster centers using
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

and its associated cluster name i.e. industrial cluster etc.
then when you have cluster centers are assigned for the data, unless the data has significantly changed the cluster center should remain relatively the same.
Get the new centroids:
New_centroids = lastes_kmeans.cluster_centers_

then you can resign the cluster centroids name with corresponding names.
